# How can one update BGP ASN on an Azure Virtual Network Gateway?

Tags: networking, powershell, azure, bgp, as-number

I have an existing Azure Virtual Network Gateway I'm attempting to reconfigure for use for BGP, per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-bgp-resource-manager-ps/ .

However, I cannot find how to change the default ASN.

`$gateway.BgpSettingsText` currently shows:

```
{
  "Asn": 65515,
  "BgpPeeringAddress": "10.231.1.254",
  "PeerWeight": 0
}
```

I see nothing exposed in the latest AzureRm Powershell that will allow me to change this.

Is there a way to change this? Or is the only solution to `Remove-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGateway` and start over?

Comment: Have you tried modifying it from Resource Explorer?  https://resources.azure.com

Comment: I don't have an Azure subscription to test with but have you tried: converting the output to a psobject, updating the Asn property, converting back to JSON, and then updating $gateway.BgpSettingsText to the new JSON string? This will only work if the object definition will allow setting that property.